# Values not being passed to handleSubmit - form POSTing it's contents in URL

Tags: material-ui, redux-form

I have created a redux form (stateless) that - as usual - has a `handleSubmit` handler passed in. Done it many times before. Form itself functions perfectly, state, validation, initialValues etc. all fine.

This form is my first that has `material-ui` components on it with wrappers based on the example on `redux-form` website, tweaked for `material-ui` v1.0.

When the submit button is pressed the `handleSubmit` function receives `undefined` for all the values passed to it from the form, and the form `POST`s itself to a URL showing all of the field contents.

> http://localhost:3000/?firstName=Steven&lastName=Bond&email=aikidoshi%40hotmail.com&password=blahdeblah

Very embarrassing!

Any suggestions welcome please. Driving me crazy.

Comment: Would need to see the code to give you a definitive answer, but it looks to me like you forgot to prevent the default HTML form submission from happening. If that is indeed the case, a simple `event.preventDefault();` as the very first instruction inside your `handleSubmit(event)` function should solve the issue.

Comment: That's odd.
const myHandleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('values:', event.target.firstName.value)
        // this works, just to prove myHandleSubmit is getting called
        //alert('submitted')
    }

Comment: Thanks Jaxx. Sorry it screwed up my previous comment.
That's odd. Normally I would just use handleSubmit(values) and get the field values directly - values.firstName. I have lots of working forms in Production use. Never had these problems, but I have just upgraded all npm modules to latest.
Doing as shown below does stop the form posting though, but then I get an undefined error if I try to access 'values' other than as shown from the DOM:

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('firstName:', event.target.firstName.value)
        )
    }